# Compile Java 11 with jacorb

Tags: java, corba, jacorb, openjdk-11

I need to compile my java CORBA applications in java 11, which no longer includes an ORB implementation.

I have included jacorb.jar in the `CLASSPATH`, but I'm still getting errors while compiling, not finding the CORBA imports:

```
import org.omg.CORBA.*
^
error: package org.omg.CORBA does not exist
```

Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: JacORB doesn't have that package. See https://jacorb.github.io/JacORB/ It's not a drop-in replacement

Comment: Thanks for your comment...In that case , something I don't understand is why the examples of the jacorb developers guide, includes    import  org.omg.CORBA.  see https://www.jacorb.org/releases/3.9/ProgrammingGuide.pdf  My feeling was that thre should be some 'trick' in the same way as when it is executed:  -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton

Comment: See on top of page 14. You also need to include other JARs in the classpath. Without looking thoroughly, I suspect that the packages you want are inside `jacorb-omgapi.jar`

Comment: Claro que si!!   Absolutely. Works like a charm. Many thanks, Federico

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Then why I'm getting the same error while trying to build JacORB source code?

Comment: @MehdiCharife sorry, no idea.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca No problem. I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77290757/maven-complains-that-org-omg-corba-does-not-exist-while-trying-to-build-jacorb) regarding this issue if you might be interested.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the JAR you're including in the classpath doesn't have that package.

You also need to include `jacorb-omgapi.jar`.

While you're at it you should do what the [documentation](https://www.jacorb.org/releases/3.9/ProgrammingGuide.pdf) says on page 14 and include all of

- `acorb.jar` - containing the ORB, IMR, IR and NamingService
- `jacorb-omgapi.jar` - containing the core OMG API stubs.
- `jacorb-services.jar` - containing all other services (e.g. Notification, DDS, Collection etc).
- `idl.jar` - containing the IDL compiler.