# Maven complains that "org.omg.CORBA" does not exist while trying to build JacORB

Tags: java, maven, circular-dependency, corba, jacorb

I'm trying to build [JacORB](https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/tree/master) via Maven under version 17 of the JDK. I've run the command `mvn clean install` as instructed in page 14 of the [docs](https://www.jacorb.org/releases/3.9/ProgrammingGuide.pdf), but got the following error:

```
[ERROR] /home/mehdi/JacORB/idl-compiler/src/main/java/org/jacorb/idl/StructType.java:[146,29] package org.omg.CORBA does not exist
```

The error seems to originate from the `idl-compiler` module.
The block that corresponds to the error is this:

```
public int getTCKind() {
    return org.omg.CORBA.TCKind._tk_struct;
}
```

The package `org.omg.CORBA` seems to exist under the module `omgapi` of the same project, so I thought to try and include this module as a dependency in the pom file of `idl-compiler` as follows:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jacorb</groupId>
     <artifactId>jacorb-omgapi</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, after running `mvn clean install` I got a complaint about cyclic dependencies:

> [ERROR] [ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic
> reference: Edge between
> 'Vertex{label='org.jacorb:jacorb-idl-compiler:3.10-SNAPSHOT'}' and
> 'Vertex{label='org.jacorb:jacorb-omgapi:3.10-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to
> cycle in the graph org.jacorb:jacorb-omgapi:3.10-SNAPSHOT -->
> org.jacorb:jacorb-idl-compiler:3.10-SNAPSHOT -->
> org.jacorb:jacorb-omgapi:3.10-SNAPSHOT @

This doesn't seem to make sense as the pom file of the module `omgapi` doesn't have any `<dependencies>`. Is there a way to solve this?

I also tried to remove the dependency and then execute the command:

```
mvn clean install -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB
```

But got the same error indicating that there is no `org.omg.CORBA` package.

Not sure if this might be helpful, but when I `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get the following result:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
```